# How to stop main scrollbar working when popup modal is activated, which needs also a scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow

I think that my question is poorly worded, but i'll try to explain. As you can see at this website **[wookmark.com](http://wookmark.com)**, when you clicking at image, than popup modal will be activated and main page scrollbar disabled. However, when modal is activated, scrollbar only working with that modal and as i was saying before - main page scrollbar are disabled when modal is activated.

**Q:** How to make this? I need that srollbar will working with modal after click, and main page will freeze.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="modal"></div>

<div id="maincontent">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

#modal {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  width:400px;
  height:1800px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:black;
  border:5px solid blue;
  display:none;
}

#maincontent { margin:50px auto; width:100%; }

.test { float:left; margin:0 5px 5px 0; width:24%; height:100px; background:red; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
  $('#modal').show();
  });
});
```

**Jsfiddle demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/1ao9gt9L/1/

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/azmObz)**

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      close: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.rofl').removeClass('fixed');
      }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      $('.rofl').addClass('fixed')
    });
  });
```

The idea is simple. We take jQuery UI's dialog and adding class `fixed` to the `.wrapper` element on dialog open. On dialog close, we remove that `fixed` class.

Comment: Nice :) well, i dont need dialog box or the UI stuff, i just need simple modal box :), but the concept is fine for me :) ty!